# php array creation like (''=>'')

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

What is difference between `$prefix=array(''=>'');` and `$prefix=array();`
what exactly `$prefix=array(''=>'');` using for ?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a difference, both are arrays. The difference is, the latter has an array key.
For instance,

```
$test1=array(1,2,3,4,5);
$test2=array('name'=>'bob','lastname'=>'fossil');
```

will return;

```
print_r($test1[0]);
//1
print_r($test2['name']." ".$test2['lastname']);
//bob fossil
```

Basically, it gives the value a name

key=>val

can be used like this

```
foreach($test2 as $val){
    echo$val;
}

//bob
//fossil
```

Answer (score 0):

It's used for creating [associative arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

No difference. first option creates an array with some elements at once, the second creates an empty array.